# Is there a way to have a persistent variable available to all methods in a /lib job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm writing the following job:

```
/lib/contact_import_job.rb
```

In this job I have:

```
def perform
  current_user = XXX.user
  my_method(21)
end
private
my_method(i)
  is there a way to get current_user here w/o having to pass it???
end
```

Is there a way to use current_user in my_method, without having to pass it? I have several of these private methods and it seems annoying to have to pass current_user to each one?

Ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define the job as a class, so you could have

```
class ContactImporterJob 

  def initialize(user)
    @user = user
  end

  def perform
    # Do all the stuff here, accessing @user for the user
  end

  private
  # Private methods still have access to @user
end
```

That way your script can send the current user in once and not have to keep passing it around. Like :

```
job = ContactImporterJob.new(current_user)
job.perform
```

Comment: That sounds exactly like what I was looking for. Let me try that now.

Answer (score 0):

You should always pass "states" to your external methods, even if they can get it without passing. So pass your `current_user` and other session based data. So it will be easier to use and to **test it**.

Good luck